# Loading Correct Page for Running C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am totally new to Visual Studio and C#. I created a test application with hard coded values to pass to my search query and was able to display the data on a web page using IIS Express in VS.  Now I have written new code that will accept user input and query the input with a return result.  My local host cannot be found.  I am not sure if I set my Startup.cs correctly.  It gets to the UseEndpoints portion and dies.

Here is my file:

```cs
namespace MyMusicApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            // Register Forecast repository
            services.AddScoped<IArtistRepository, ArtistRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Shared/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();



            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=MyMusicApp}/{action=SearchArtist}/{id?}");
            });


        }
    }
}
```

Here is some hierarchy of my files:

- Controllers:  MusicAppController.cs
- Views: ArtistInformation
  (folder)
- ArtistInformation.cshtml (file)
- SearchArtist.cshtml (file)

I have models (.cs) that I populate from my JSON response and I have models (.cs) to help display (I think)

Here are the models for populating views:

```cs
public class ArtistInformation
{
    [Display(Name = "Artist:")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title:")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Album:")]
    public string album { get; set; }
}

public class SearchArtist
{
    // Annotations required to validate input data in our model.
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter an artist name!")]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only text allowed")]
    [Display(Name = "Artist Name")]
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the views:

```cs
@model MyMusicApp.MusicAppModels.SearchArtist

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SearchArtist";
}

<div class="container">

    <form method="post">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
                <h2>Search the forecast in a city</h2>
                <label asp-for="ArtistName" style="font-family: Arial"></label>
                <input asp-for="ArtistName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ArtistName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
                <button asp-controller="MusicAppController" asp-action="SearchArtistSongTitles" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

ArtistInformationView:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ArtistInformation";
}
<h1>ArtistInformation</h1>
<div class="container">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
            <h4>Artist Song Title and Album Information for  @Model.data[1].artist.name</h4>
            <hr />
            <img src=@Model.data[1].artist.picture_big style="width:32px" />
            @foreach (var var in Model.data)
            {
                <div>
                    <div>Song title: @var.title</div>
                    <div>Album:  @var.album.title</div>
                    <img src=@var.album.cover_xl style="width:32px" />
                    <hr />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">

            <form method="get">
                <button asp-controller="MusicAppController" asp-action="SearchArtistSongTitles" class="btn btn-success">Return</button>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Like I said, my code when simply displaying the response with the index.cshtml that was auto generated when I created the initial project worked.  Now I've added much more.

Any help to get this to on start display the search page and then upon search to display the ArtistInformation.

Comment: Can you please change the title to say what the actual problem is?

Comment: I changed the title sorry.

Comment: That is still not correct. The title should be a question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the map pattern in `Startup.cs` I think you have the wrong controller name. Your controller is named `MusicAppController.cs` but you have put your controller map route pattern as

`pattern: "{controller=MyMusicApp}/{action=SearchArtist}/{id?}");`

Try change it to

`pattern: "{controller=MusicApp}/{action=SearchArtist}/{id?}");`

Also, I'm assuming you have an action in your controller called `SearchArtist`

Comment: Did this answer your question?